# How can I declare an array property?

Tags: delphi, oop, delphi-7, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010

I constructed class system

```
  TTableSpec=class(Tobject)
  private
    FName : string;
    FDescription : string;
    FCan_add : Boolean;
    FCan_edit : Boolean;
    FCan_delete : Boolean;
    FFields : array[1..100] of TFieldSpec;
  public
    property Name: String read FName;
    property Description: String read FDescription;
    property Can_add : Boolean read FCan_add;
    property Can_edit : Boolean read FCan_edit;
    property Can_delete : Boolean read FCan_delete;
    property Fields : array read FFields;
  end;
```

Thus in TableSpec Fields property shall be the list of fields (I used TFieldSpec array). How to organize the list of fields (using or without using an array) as as a result of compilation I receive an error

```
[Error] Objects.pas(97): Identifier expected but 'ARRAY' found
[Error] Objects.pas(97): READ or WRITE clause expected, but identifier 'FFields' found
[Error] Objects.pas(98): Type expected but 'END' found
[Hint] Objects.pas(90): Private symbol 'FFields' declared but never used
[Fatal Error] FirstTask.dpr(5): Could not compile used unit 'Objects.pas'
```

Comment: Unless you're certain that you'll need exactly 100 fields, I'd create a type like `type TFields=Array of TFieldSpec`  and then specify the fields attribute as `FFields:TFields`.

Comment: Renamed the title, and removed irrelevant code. We don't need to see the entire unit in order to pinpoint the problem here.

Comment: Are you sure you want a property with an array type, or rather an indexer?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your line

```
property Fields : array read FFields;
```

is invalid syntax. It should be

```
property Fields[Index: Integer]: TFieldSpec read GetField;
```

where `GetField` is a (private) function that takes an integer (the `Index`)  and returns the corresponding `TFieldSpec`, e.g.,

```
function TTableSpec.GetField(Index: Integer): TFieldSpec;
begin
  result := FFields[Index];
end;
```

See [the documentation on array properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Properties#Array_Properties).

Comment: Yes, sorry thats escaped my attention. (:

Answer (score 14):

I agree the answer regarding INDEXED properties, given by Andreas, is the solution the poster is looking for.

For completeness, for future visitors, I'd like to point out that a property can have an array type, as long as the type is named. The same applies to records, pointers, and other derived types.

```
type
  tMyColorIndex = ( Red, Blue, Green );
  tMyColor = array [ tMyColorIndex ] of byte;

  tMyThing = class
    private
      fColor : tMyColor;
    public
      property Color : tMyColor read fColor;
  end;
```