# Delphi - How can I pass an array of TAlignment itens to property?

Tags: arrays, delphi, properties

I want to configure the alignment at runtime of some columns of a DBGrid that's inside a component, passing the alignment of each column as an array to a property, but I'm confusing about that.

I guess the code in component should be something like that (according Andreas Rejbrand reply in [How can I declare an array property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871142/how-can-i-declare-an-array-property)):

```
property MyAlignment[Index: Integer]: TAlignment read GetMyAlignment;

function MyComponent.GetMyAlignment(Index: Integer): TAlignment;
begin
  result := FMyAlignment[Index];
end;
```

How do I mount the array that will be pass to the component's property ?

I try the code below but I'm getting the error "[dcc32 Error] uCad.pas(31): E2188 Published property 'ColumnTitleName' cannot be of type ARRAY".

```
type
    TCad = class
    private
      FColumnTitleName: array of String;
      FColumnTitleAlign: array of TAlignment;
      FColumnAlign: array of TAlignment;
      function GetColumnAlignment(index: Integer): TAlignment;
      function GetColumnTitleAlignment(index: Integer): TAlignment;
      function GetColumnTitleName(index: Integer): String;
    public

    published
      property ColumnTitleName[index: Integer]: String read GetColumnTitleName;
      property ColumnTitleAlign[index: Integer]: TAlignment read GetColumnTitleAlign;
      property ColumnAlign[index: Integer]: TAlignment read GetColumnAlignment;
  end;

implementation

function TCad.GetColumnAlign(index: Integer): TAlignment;
begin
  Result := FColumnAlign[index];
end;

function TCad.GetColumnTitleAlign(index: Integer): TAlignment;
begin
  Result := FColumnTitleAlign[index];
end;

function TCad.GetColumnTitleName(index: Integer): String;
begin
  Result := FColumnTitleName[index];
end;

end.
```

Comment: `TColumnTitle` already has `Alignment` (DB grid's column `Title`).

Comment: Sorry. I think I did not explain it correctly. The number of fields and alignments in the DBGrid will differ depending on an external SQL query to the component.

Comment: Are you saying you want to iterate the grid columns and set the alignment property based on an array?

Comment: You don't pass an array to that property. **It is read-only**. So you can only do something like `YourTAlignment :=  MyComponent.MyAlignment[17];`.

Comment: You should link to that *reply on another topic* if you're going to cite it, so we can see what it actually says. Putting it in **bold to make it stand out** doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: John Easley. That's it. I want to iterate the grid columns and set the alignment property based on the received array.

Comment: RE update: You cannot publish an array property.